# fixing a truecrypt volume

Tags: truecrypt, headers, logical-drive

I believe that I have corrupted my volume header on one of my truecrypt volumes because I have tried the password tons of times and it hasn't worked.

My idea is to create another volume with the same password and then take the header of the new volume and make it the old corrupted volumes header.

I am wondering if this is possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This question will be migrated to Superuser, no doubt, but no, it's not possible.

Well, making a new volume with the same password, and then copying over the header is surely possible. You need a tool that can read and write disks by the sector, but yes, that part is doable.

However, your drive is still unreadable, since the key used to encrypt your volume is randomly created and then protected with the password, not derived from your password. In other words, the new volume key will not be the same as the old volume key.

If it's your system drive, you need to pop in the CD you made when you created it. If it's not a system drive (or you don't have that CD any more), you're out of luck.